# How to deal with spam

Tags: support, faq, flagging, moderation

This isn’t a question as such, but a public service announcement.

From time to time, and sometimes in waves like the current spam campaigns, the main site gets posts (both questions and answers) which are obviously spam — they are blatant attempts to get visitors to go to a site the spammer presumably cares about, or more recently, call a phone number. Most of the time these posts are quickly removed, but I have noticed some instances of well-meaning users commenting on the posts or voting to close them.

What should be done about such posts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**There is only one correct way of dealing with spam on SE**, and that is to **flag the post as spam**, and only that (in particular, do not downvote it):

[image: Flagging a post as spam]

Flagging a post in this manner doesn’t necessarily end up adding work for the site’s moderators: [once six such flags are raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/285232), the post will automatically be deleted.

Every single spam flag also results in a downvote (and in the case of answers, this doesn’t cost the flagger any reputation). Additional downvotes **are not helpful**, in fact [they can help spam survive longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193917/285232) by removing it from the front page.

Additionally, if you see a spam post that hasn’t been deleted some time after it was posted (say, ten minutes), that means it hasn’t been detected by [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector). Such posts should be reported to [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), ideally before they are deleted; doing so allows the people involved with Charcoal to adapt the detections such that future instances of similar spam are detected and reported, which tends to result in the spam more rapidly accumulating spam flags and, thus, being deleted faster.

All this is but a small part of Stack Exchange’s spam handling; see [How does spam protection work on Stack Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for posting this!

Comment: "in particular, do not downvote it" -- and this part is hilariously stupid, which of course is par for the course for SE. Downvoting to remove the spam from sight  sounds like something one might relatively naturally want to do.

Comment: @ilkkachu the ultimate removal from sight is deletion, and that can take longer if spam is removed from sight without being deleted.

Comment: @StephenKitt, yes. And if what is required for that is visibility on the front page, then spam flags should counter those downvotes to _prevent_ them from hiding the spam. There's no sense in having a feature that obviously works to remove bad stuff (from sight) which then inversely should not be used for other bad stuff. The tools should be designed to make the job easier for the user.

Comment: Thanks for this, I misremembered that a way of dealing with spam was downvoting it. Monty python would be happy with this wave of spam 

Comment: *"in particular, do not downvote it"* SE's behaviour is particularly misleading because flagging spam marks a downvote... which is the most visible effect to most users.  So without this meta-post it actually looks like everyone else is down-voting!

Comment: Don't forget that if a post is flagged as spam, it goes into the VLQ review queue where reviewers will see it even if its negative score has removed it from the front page.

Comment: Just to put a finer point on it: closing a question means there's a (theoretical) possibility of it being edited into an answerable question. Spam doesn't fit that criteria, so just flag it towards deletion.